# Long Display Names Cause Flair Layout Issue

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, flair, display-names

Because I use my actual name for display on Stack Overflow, it is displayed outside the flair box.

Obviously, I could just shorten my display name, and this issue would go away.  And I understand the underlying CSS layout concept, but this brings to mind two questions:

- If this happens to display names as long as mine, why allow the display names to be that length?
- Should the flair box expand for longer display names, if they are to be allowed?

The CSS layout can be edited when embedding the flair on another site, perhaps we can have an option to control the flair CSS on the Careers CV display?

Comment: I think the solution is clear -- change your name. How does Ben Strozy sound? It's got quite a nice ring to it I think!

Comment: PS. That was a joke in case it wasn't clear. (Did anyone else read _Bruno and Boots_ growing up? The evil computer shortened the name of "Wilbur Hackenschleimer" to "Wilbur Hacken" so it would fit in its short DB columns. Ack, I hate explaining jokes.)

Comment: @Ether HAHA!  I hate it when people add -y to a name.  The name "Benny" haunted me in my youth.

Comment: Should this be changed to simply a [feature-request]?  I am uncertain of the protocol.

Comment: @Ether - how about `BSTR` short, snappy, programmery, mnemonicy, c++'y

Comment: @rene You are correct. This question was answered in Feb of 2010, so I'm not sure it would necessarily be worthwhile finding a replacement image of the problem. A cursory search shows I don't have one lying around, and Google Cache and archive.org don't seem to have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A change will be deployed tonight that will address this.  Names that are really long will be truncated slightly as per @Koper's suggestion

Comment: How is length defined?  And what is the length maximum?  What about a name like `́́ Ｐｒｉｍｅｒｏ̂̊`?  That has 19 code points, 15 graphemes due to the combining characters, and 22 print columns due to the wide characters. Oh, and Deseret is in the SMP, which of course does not change the length in codepoints. In case you have trouble bare-eying my string, it is: `"\x{1043C}\x{1042F}\x{301}\x{10445}\x{10428}\x{10449}\x{1042F}\x{301}\x{1043B} \x{FF30}\x{FF52}\x{FF49}\x{FF4D}\x{FF45}\x{FF52}\x{FF4F}\x{302}\x{30A}"`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Koper's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/long-display-names-cause-flair-layout-issue/39690#39690), and to answer your question, *"why allow the display names to be that length?"*, flair came along as an afterthought by which time it would have been a major annoyance to truncate existing Display Names to fit the flair dimensions.

I'm guessing there was an optimal size to fit 99% of cases, maybe you could ask for a parameter to be added that would allow you to control the flair width or fiddle with the CSS yourself:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair#js

Comment: If I were embedding the flair on an outside site (not my Careers CV), you are right, I would just override the CSS and figure something out.  I'm going to edit the question and add in the suggestion for the ability to modify it on Careers.

Comment: +1 for the parameter suggestion

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same as on stackoverflow: a `white-space: nowrap` with `overflow: hidden`; and a fixed width. In other words names that don't fit are silently truncated.

Comment: As long as there is some solution, I'm OK with it.  Just bugs me that currently my flair is broken (Once again, I know that I can shorten my display name, but that's not the issue): http://img115.yfrog.com/img115/9339/picture5.png

Answer (score 1):

I've come to the conclusion:

**Jeff doesn't like people with long names.**

Seriously, look at his name: *Jeff Atwood*

**4 letters**, and then **6 letters**, for a sum total of **10 letters plus a space**.

Thats shorter than your entire last name!

It's a conspiracy I tell ya!

Comment: I've been faced with this sort of discrimination my whole life! *tear*  Well, it was always more people horribly mangling my last name...not that I blame them.

Comment: I've been haunted with layout issues since about 3k+ rep having the display name "Jonathan Sampson". Stinks, but I'm comfortably numb to it now.

Answer (score 0):

There's whitespace in your name, and room for more than one line of text, so I don't see why wrapping couldn't be used here. (CSS left as an exercise for those more well-versed in CSS.)