# Very wide display names cause flair layout issue part 2

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

Looking at the accounts for this [user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158489/status-access-denied?tab=accounts) in Chrome, the width of display name prevents the icon from each SE site from being visible:

I found a similar issue that was fixed a year ago where the name would display below the flair:

[Long Display Names Cause Flair Layout Issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/long-display-names-cause-flair-layout-issue)

However this current case is a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We no longer use flair on the accounts page, but you can still sort of see the issue in the flair:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158489/status-access-denied?tab=flair

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the built-in flair, [StackImage 2](https://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair) allows you to change the size of your flair including its width. Using this tool (**disclaimer:** I wrote it), you can completely customize your flair's dimensions, borders, contents, etc.

In your case, you would want to make sure that there is plenty of room for the 'Display Name' component so that your username will fit on one line.

Comment: Looks like the user page has changed away from flair since this question was posted.  Doesn't look like it is an issue anymore as the new layout uses the site name instead of the user name.  (Although I think the user name should be used instead).