# flair doesn't fit my name

Tags: feature-request, flair

Is there a way that I could edit the image of the of my stack overflow user flair? Seems like I was given birth with a very long name lol :))
Below is the image of my flair. I hope somebody could help me change this.
My reputation is not that big but I'm very proud to be part of the community.

[image: My Flair]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82294/very-wide-display-names-cause-flair-layout-issue-part-2

Comment: What do your friends call you?  Use that.

Comment: I don't want to change my name on my profile. What I am after is, stackoverflow displays first if someone search my name at google they would see it on the first row. On my point of view, it is an advantage if an employer search for my name and the first that would display related to my name is my account on stackoverflow. I doubt if employers would type my nickname as the keyword for google search. I do hope you get my point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [StackFlair - **Defunct** Generate flair for your Stack Exchange associated accounts](https://stackapps.com/questions/1567/stackflair-generate-flair-for-your-stackexchange-associated-accounts-please-sw) to report bug issues, or to grab the code and make your own custom flair.

Comment: Isn't this the regular SE flair (despite being uploaded to imgur) and not StackFlair—so the bug wouldn't be with StackFlair?

Comment: @waiwai933 My understanding is that after seeing what RChern wrote, they adopted it, with modification, as the standard SO flair.  If you recall, the previous flair was HTML based, while this is image based.  But my understanding is that the base of the new flair stems from RChern's work. I could be wrong though. Either way you are correct, the code is obviously different now, and it's quite possible that discussing bug reports there won't help SE.  However, RChern is a member of the staff now, and may well be maintaining the internal version as well. Either way, she's a good contact for this.