# Flair not having the entire Display name in it

Tags: feature-request, design, flair

As you can see, my Display name is **Tiago Martins Peres 李大仁**. Yet, when looking at [the flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/7465632/tiago-martins-peres-%E6%9D%8E%E5%A4%A7%E4%BB%81?tab=flair), the last character isn't showing up completely (can see a tiny part of it).

[image: Flair not having the entire Display name]

In no point whatsoever during the establishment of the Display name I was informed that using this name would generate problems in the flair.

Some solutions I can see to this problem:

- Inform the user that having a Display name with length bigger than 28 will not show the entire name in the flair
- Block the user from having a display name larger than length 28
- Find a way to fit the entire name in the flair (for instances by shrinking the size of some parts), like it was done when a [similar problem happened back in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39723/364217).

Comment: Interestingly, your username also gets slightly wrapped for me, on this post. The last character is on a new line.

Comment: I don't think this is something usefull to implement. The small percentage that uses their flair will see it when their flair is rendered and can then choose to change their display name. For the other 99% of users this is not a problem.

Comment: this might be as simple as pointing this out on the flare page

Comment: We can't notify users of specific character lengths because characters take up different amounts of space. It wouldn't always truncate at the same number of characters as yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long Display Names Cause Flair Layout Issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/long-display-names-cause-flair-layout-issue)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not a duplicate. That post is marked [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog the answer explains that truncation was part of the solution.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The current name *is* truncated. This is a new report, not related to that report in any form.